ta.barssince returns a NAN value
I have an input that lets a user submit a timestamp for when an indicator should look back to however when I try and get the number of bars since the supplied time I am getting a value of NaN on the daily chart.
//@version=5
indicator("My Indicator")
startDate = input.time(timestamp("August 08 2024"), "Start date", group = 'Lookback Properties')
lookBack = ta.barssince(time == startDate)
log.info("lookBack = {0}", lookBack)

The output I am getting looks like this:
[2024-10-16T13:30:00.000-00:00]: lookBack = NaN

How should I be implementing ta.barssince to get the number of bars since a timestamp?

ta.barssince() wants a condition as an argument, not a timestamp, see Pine Script Functions. For the bars since a timestamp you can calculate the time delta and then divide it by the time frame, e.g. 120 minutes delta divided by 5 minutes bars (time frame) will give 24 bars as a result
